# Syntax for netsh http url reservation for any IP address

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express, netsh

I'm using IIS Express as my development web server with Visual Studio 2012.  I want to be able to reach my site from wireless devices (smartphones, tablets, etc.) for testing and debugging.  The wireless devices are on a separate LAN from the workstation, and are not part of my Windows AD.  Because of the way my office LAN is set up, they cannot resolve my workstation by hostname; they must use the IP address.

For IIS Express to be reachable through non-localhost URLs, I have to change its configuration in applicationhost.config to add a binding that uses the IP address, and then use `netsh http add urlacl...` to make a URL reservation.

I can make it work fine if I use the IP address in the reservation and the applicationhost.config.  But IP addresses do change occasionally.  Is there any way to use the wildcard syntax so it works for any IP address?  I tried these:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:49197/ user=everyone`

and

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:49197/ user=everyone`

But when I try to start IIS Express, it complains that it can't start because access is denied.

What's the right syntax for this?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this ?

Comment: I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with admin user. As you might not have the rights

netsh http add urlacl url=link user=BUILTIN\Administrators